Terraform does not accept Snowflake account name
I keep getting this message:
"account_name": all of `account_name,organization_name` must be specified
Even when I explicitly give it my account name and organization name in the exact format it is asking for (I fully gave up trying to make this work as a variable.
I've tried every permutation I can think of and it never accepts any of it as valid. I'm baffled because I got this working on a different project just yesterday.
I know this will be downvoted to oblivion because it's so vague but I literally have no idea.

SELECT CURRENT_ORGANIZATION_NAME(), CURRENT_ACCOUNT_NAME();

If you can add the code you’re running to your question that may help people give you some guidance

Thanks - I found this in the change logs for the latest version, should've checked that sooner. So much stuff online (including copilot) says the account_name should be <org-name>-<account-name>; and some also say you need region etc. Turns out it's all been simplified to just need the output of @LukaszSzozda's query

Values for organization and account names can be determined by running:
SELECT CURRENT_ORGANIZATION_NAME(), CURRENT_ACCOUNT_NAME();

